# Understanding how scss and minified files work in VS2017

Tags: css, sass

I am not familiar with scss at all.

We have a .scss file named Theme6.scss. In Visual Studio 2017 solution explorer, if I expand that file, I see a file named Theme6.css. If I expand that file, I see 2 files: Theme6.css.map, Theme6.min.css

Inside the map file, there is a line that reads

```
"file": "Theme6.css",
```

Now I have edited that Theme6.css with some CSS updates, but that change does not make it into either the min file or this special scss file.

How do I update the CSS? Which file should I be editing, and what does each of the above files do?

Answer (score 0):

SCSS:- It is a CSS Preprocessor, which converts all the SCSS files to CSS.

If you make changes in SCSS that will not be reflected to your application because you need to convert SCSS to CSS. Browsers Just read CSS but not SCSS.

SCSS gives flexibility to make use of Variables, mixins, loops etc.
SCSS is advanced level of writing CSS.

Map files are used by browsers to map the CSS to the SCSS files.

Comment: Right, so how do I convert scss to css?